# SQL Server 2016, Troubles with function to check user login and hashed pasword in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, case-statement

I cannot figure out why this function will not return the Else of the Case function.

I send values (userlogin and pw) to the function via an MS Access dynamically modified SQL Pass through Query. If I've entered correct values for UserLogin and UserPw, the function works fine - it returns "Valid". If the values I send to the function aren't matched, it is supposed to send back the value "Invalid". It sends back nothing, a Null value I believe.

How do I construct this Case statement properly?

Thanks in advance!

```
ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[Password_Check]
    (
        @UserPW varchar(500),
        @UserLogin nvarchar(255)
    )
    RETURNS  varchar(7)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result varchar(7)
 
 
    Select
        @result  =( CASE when [HPWD] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @UserPW + CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))) AND [UserLogin] = @UserLogin  THEN 'Valid'
                    ELSE 'Invalid'
        END )
        from dbo.tblUser
        where  [HPWD] =  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @UserPW + CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))) AND [UserLogin] = @UserLogin
 
    RETURN @result
    END
```

Comment: This is due to the fact that your first CASE statement and WHERE clause is exactly same. Assign some other values in WHERE clause and you will get the desired output

Also, on what behalf you want to filter records. Please explain

Comment: I want the function to try to find the record in tblUser that matches both UserLogin, and the hashed and salted password. If it does, then return text "Valid", if it doesn't find a matching record, then return text "Invalid". So, I thought I had to include that in the Where. Perhaps I don't, since the Case is checking for a matching record?

Comment: Yes... CASE  statement is already checking it.

Comment: @J.Smoots Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is because your else clause never happens. It is filtered out by **where** condition. You can set first the invalid condition, and everything else you already have in place

```sql
ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[Password_Check]
    (
        @UserPW varchar(500),
        @UserLogin nvarchar(255)
    )
    RETURNS  varchar(7)
    AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result varchar(7)
    set @result = 'Invalid'
 
    select  @result  = 'Valid'
        from dbo.tblUser
        where 
            [HPWD] =  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @UserPW + CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))) 
            AND [UserLogin] = @UserLogin
 
    return @result
END
```

Comment: Excellent! This works wonderfully. Many thanks to you!